# Numbers x such that x^2 divides 7^x-1

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Task

There is a set of numbers `x`, such that `x^2` divides `7^x-1`.

Your task is to find these numbers. Given an input of n, the code will print the nth number that follows this rule.

## Examples 1-index

```
In   Out
3    3
9    24
31   1140
```

The relevant sequence can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A127107).

### Rules

Shortest answer will be the winner*

Standard golfing rules apply

[Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed

Your answer can either be 0 or 1 indexed, please state in your answer

Comment: @nimi I wrote these down when planning and never implemented them. I've updated the question

Comment: What are the limits of `n`? I can give the correct result with `n=9`, but `n=10` is already causing me problems.

Comment: @briantist If you're getting the wrong result for higher input values, your answer is wrong. If it's just taking a long time, that can be implementation dependent.

Comment: It's not just taking a long time. `n=10` gives me 32; it's because it starts using double instead of integers and the mod is wrong after that. :(

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
([x|x<-[1..],mod(7^x-1)(x^2)<1]!!)
```

This uses 0-based indexing. Usage example: `([x|x<-[1..],mod(7^x-1)(x^2)<1]!!) 30` -> `1140`.

It's a direct implementation of the definition. It builds a list of all numbers `x` and picks the `n`th.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
e.f!%t^7Z*
```

A program that takes input of an integer and prints a one-indexed value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@5@ql6aoWhJnHqX1/7@xIQA)

**How it works**

```
e.f!%t^7Z*     Program. Input: Q
e.f!%t^7Z*ZZQ  Implicit variable fill
               Implicitly print
e              the last
 .f         Q  of the first Q positive integers Z
     t^7Z      for which 7^Z - 1
    %          mod
         *ZZ   Z^2
   !           is zero
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 40 bytes

```
f=(n,i=1)=>n?f(n-!((7**++i-1)%i**2),i):i
```

This loses precision fairly quickly due to the fact that JS loses precision by `7**19`. Here's a nearly arbitrary-precision ES6 version:

```
f=(n,i=0)=>n?f(n-!(~-(s=++i*i,g=j=>j?g(j-1)*7%s:1)(i)%s),i):i
```

This finishes within about a second for test case 31.

A few longer approaches:

```
f=(n,i=0)=>n?f(n-!(~-(s=>g=j=>j?g(j-1)*7%s:1)(++i*i)(i)%s),i):i
f=(n,i=0)=>n?f(n-!(s=++i*i,g=(j,n=1)=>j?g(j-1,n*7%s):~-n%s)(i),i):i
f=(n,i=0)=>n?f(n-!(s=>g=(j,n=1)=>j?g(j-1,n*7%s):~-n%s)(++i*i)(i),i):i
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
µ7Nm<NnÖiN¼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39oq7lfro1f3uFpmX6H9vz/b2wIAA)

For some reason I can't get `½` to work in `µ7Nm<NnÖ½N` or I'd be tied with Pyth.

```
µ           # Loop until the counter equals n.
 7Nm<       # Calc 7^x+1.
     Nn     # Calc x^2.
       Ö    # Check divisibility.
        iN¼ # If divisible, push current x and increment counter.
            # Implicit loop end.
            # Implicitly return top of stack (x)
```

.

Comment: Yeah, I've had that quirk with `Ö` on my fix list for months but I never get around to dealing with it. Anyways, you don't need the `N` as `µ` automatically outputs the last `N` if the stack is empty.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

*Thanks to @Dennis for -2 bytes!*

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n and-~f(n-(~-7**i%i**2<1),i+1)
```

A one-indexed recursive function that takes input via argument and returns the result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcxBCsIwEEDRfU8xFAJJTIRpBbFYLyIuom1hoJmUTFy46dVrFn/3@BS3lAvIT5raWeaS5883CyVeKVLRiJfOHMu4hvieArCjEQeGwJPfF81e7/5qLSmytrujcXTCylMGBmJ49g5uDnp8DQ1smbjoVgn4ByhplWZXF8aY4w8) (Recursion limit increased to allow the final test case to run)

**How it works**

`n` is the desired index, and `i` is the counting variable.

The expression `~-7**i%i**2<1` returns `True` (equivalent to `1`) if `i^2` divides `7^i - 1`, and `False` (equivalent to `0`) otherwise. Each time the function is called, the result of the expression is subtracted from `n`, decrementing `n` each time a hit is found; `i` is also incremented.

The short-circuiting behaviour of `and` means that when `n` is `0`, `0` is returned; this is the base case. Once this is reached, recursion stops, and the current value of `i` is returned by the original function call. Rather than explicitly using `i`, this is done using the fact that for each function call, an increment has been performed using the `-~` in front of the call; incrementing `0` `i` times gives `i`, as required.

Comment: `(~-7**i%i**2<1)` saves a couple of bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>57</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to ETHproductions</sup>
<sup>-2 bytes thanks to TuukkaX</sup>

```python
i=0
g=input()
while g:i+=1;g-=~-7**i%i**2<1
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59pa8CVbpuZV1BaoqHJVZ6RmZOqkG6VqW1raJ2ua1una66llamaqaVlZGPIVVCUmVeikPn/vyUA)
the sequence is 1-indexed

Comment: @ETHproductions yep c:

Comment: Does a testcase fail if you remove the parentheses around `(7**i)`? I removed them and it worked for the ones I tried.

Comment: @TuukkaX indeed, `**` has a higher precedence than `~` and `-`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 57 bytes

This takes a really, *really* long time for large values. It also uses plenty of memory, because it builds the entire list way farther than necessary. The result is zero-indexed.

```python
lambda n:[x for x in range(1,2**n+1)if(7**x-1)%x**2<1][n]
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBnFV2hkJZfpFChkJmnUJSYl56qYahjpKWVp22omZmmYa6lVaFrqKlaoaVlZGMYG50X@7@gKDOvRCFNw1LzPwA)

Comment: out of curiosity, is there any proof for the `2**n+1` as upper limit?

Comment: @Rod Not that I know of, but considering that there are 50 values < 5000, I'm sure there's a lot more than 50 < `2**50`. I could use `9**n+9`, but it takes much much longer. I started running `f(20)` a while ago (with `2**n+1`); it still hasn't completed.

Comment: I don't even think there's a proof that the sequence is infinite, let alone a nice upper bound for the nth term!

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 43 bytes

I've currently got three different solutions at this byte count:

```
Nest[#+1//.x_/;!(x^2∣(7^x-1)):>x+1&,0,#]&
Nest[#+1//.x_/;Mod[7^x-1,x^2]>0:>x+1&,0,#]&
Nest[#+1//.x_:>x+Sign@Mod[7^x-1,x^2]&,0,#]&
```

Comment: What is the character between x^2 and (7^x... in the first line? It looks like a pipe but shorter

Comment: @Sefa It's the Unicode character for the mathematical "divides" symbol and is used by Mathematica as an operator for `Divisible`.

Comment: Here is one at 41 Bytes: `Cases[Range[#^3],x_/;x^2∣(7^x-1)][[#]]&` based on the heuristic argument that n^3 is an upper bound. I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain :)

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 42 bytes

Pretty straightforward. 1-indexed, though this could easily be changed.

```
n->=k=1;while(n--,while((7^k++-1)%k^2,));k
```

or

```
n->=k=1;for(i=2,n,while((7^k++-1)%k^2,));k
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n<2or-~f(n-(7**k%k**2==1),k+1)
```

Return *True* for input **1**, which is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9067/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#RYpBCsIwFETX9hSfQiA/TaUJYqEY71JtKyHNT0niwo1Xr0VFB4Z5PMb6JcQM6ZGKrfs05jhe7zHZQLP1NnPdNA2uk5l7fxl6IOmM7uikQ6yfE6eat0I45oTQxiiUrlLbO0QgsASxp9vI1RG7YrdES5mXTA9Qn4EdBvjmb0pgwAkqUBKmD6CE97Y/0yLi@gI)

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but I assume it returns a value for other inputs? Rather than a bool?

Answer (score 1):

## R, 35 bytes

This only works for `n<=8`.

```
z=1:20;which(!(7^z-1)%%z^2)[scan()]
```

However, here's a longer version which works for `n<=25`, for **50 bytes**:

```
z=1:1e6;which(gmp::as.bigz(7^z-1)%%z^2==0)[scan()]
```

Comment: Does this only work up to `8` because it become a long int?

Comment: @george Yes, you lose accuracy as R defaults to 32 bit integers. The second version of the code uses a package, `gmp`, which allows arbitrarily large integers. However, I rapidly run out of RAM for computing anything above `n=25`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
{grep({(7**$_-1)%%$_²},^∞)[$_]}
```

0-indexed.

Shaved off one byte thanks to Brad Gilbert.

Comment: grep is a subroutine so you can remove the space if you put the parens after it `{grep(…)}`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>47</s> 49 bytes

```php
while($n<$argv[1])$n+=(7**++$x-1)%$x**2<1;echo$x;
```

Only works for n<9 (`7**9` is larger than `PHP_INT_MAX` with 64bit)

**62 bytes** using arbitrary length integers: (not tested; PHP on my machine doesn´t have bcmath)

```php
for($x=$n=1;$n<$argv[1];)$n+=bcpowmod(7,++$x,$x**2)==1;echo$x;
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>' <n>`.

**pseudo code**

```
implicit: $x = 0, $n = 0
while $n < first command line argument
    increment $x
    if equation is satisfied
        increment $n
print $x
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
~1IX7i^tR%
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7E1IX7i%5EtR%25&input=9)

```
~1         -  infinite(1)
  IX7i^tR% - filter(^, not V)
    7i^    -    7**i
       t   -   ^-1
        R% -  ^ % v
   X       -   i**2
           - implicit: print nth value
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 83 bytes

```clj
(fn[n](nth(filter #(= 0(rem(-(reduce *(repeat % 7N))1)(* % %)))(iterate inc 1N))n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clojure#DYxBCoMwFET3OcVAEeYLBW0X7aZX8AIhC9EfGtBfG1Pw9jabx4PHzMlZI6IDGM1boJU3Y1qKZlz4QsesK6@V829StFU2HQsaPAaRXthWbUSEqU7Gokg2oa/NRJw4x/mz6xf@ANdxQ4S/4Yl7FySAW05WFgP3knHUl/P8Aw)

This builds an infinite list of Java BigIntegers starting at 1 and filters them by the definition. It uses zero-based indexing to select the *n<sup>th</sup>* value from the filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 35 Bytes

Well, this was missing, so here it is:

`map{$_ if!((7**$_-1)%($_**2))}1..<>`

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, too many bytes

Just to see if it was possible and it is.

```
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(1,10000)|?{[System.Numerics.BigInteger]::Remainder([System.Numerics.BigInteger]::Pow(7,$_)-1,$_*$_) -eq 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 39 bytes

```
:{~(7^q-1)%(q^2)=0|b=b+1]~b=a|_Xq\q=q+1
```

I couldn't get it to run in QBasic 4.5, but it seems to run fine in QB64. For some inexplicable reason, QBasic refuses to cleanly divide 13,841,287,200 by 144, but instead gives a remainder of -128. It then returns 16 as the 7th term of this sequence instead of 12...

```
:{      get N from the command line, start an infinite DO-loop
~       IF
(7^q-1) Part 1 of the formula (Note that 'q' is set to 1 as QBIC starts)
%       Modulus
(q^2)   The second part
=0      has no remainder
|b=b+1  Then, register a 'hit'
]       END IF
~b=a    If we have scored N hits
|_Xq    Quit, printing the last used number (q)
\q=q+1  Else, increase q by 1. 
        [DO-loop and last IF are implicitly closed by QBIC]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 28 bytes

```
@:^#0(!>@! % - ^7#0 1^#0 2)N
```

Zero-indexed. Usage:

```
(@:^#0(!>@! % - ^7#0 1^#0 2)N)2
```

Filters from the list of natural numbers with a predicate that determines whether `x^2` is divisible by `7^x-1`, then gets the nth item in that list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 73 bytes

```
while {[incr i]} {if 0==(7**$i-1)%$i**2 {incr j;if $j==$n break}}
puts $i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@V@cWqKQp2D5vzwjMydVoTo6My@5SCEztlahOjNNwcDWVsNcS0slU9dQU1UlU0vLCCgMUpBlDZRVybK1VclTSCpKTcyureUqKC0pVlDJ/P8fAA)